# Tikz: How to fill an intersection of two arcs?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to fill the intersection of two arcs like this:

[image]

I wrote some code and drew the shape:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,color}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2, 4);
\coordinate (D) at (-2,4);

\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(A);

%Draw the arcs 
\draw[color=gray] (2,0) arc (0:90:4); % around A
\draw[color=gray] (-2,4) arc (180:270:4); % around C


\draw[color=gray] (2,4) arc (90:180:4); % around B
\draw[color=gray] (-2,0) arc (270:360:4); % around D

\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gets me this:

[image]

I experimented a bit with clip and fill but it didn't work. How can I fill the middle intersection part?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

You can only fill closed paths. I clip with one closed leaf and fill the other. The drawing of the lines comes after - `--cycle` is to have nicer mitred joins.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip (2,0) arc (0:90:4) arc (180:270:4) -- cycle;
\fill[gray] (2,4) arc (90:180:4) arc (270:360:4) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\draw (2,0) arc (0:90:4) arc (180:270:4) -- cycle;
\draw(2,4) arc (90:180:4) arc (270:360:4) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Filled leaf]

Comment: Thank you! What does scope do?

Comment: Oooh! I had not seen this way of using two arc commands in one draw statement! Thank you! I think this will solve my problem!

Comment: `scope` is just a scope. The `\clip` ends when the scope does, so nothing after is clipped.