# How to fill the area enclosed by two shapes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have two lines; one a "curly" line and the other a vertex (seeMWE below):

[image: Two lines]

How can I fill the area enclosed by these two lines? That is, between the red and black lines?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots,pgfplotstable,amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [ultra thick,red] (-19.5,-16) to[out=55,in=228] (-14,-9) to [out=45,in=180] (0,-2) to[out=0,in=135] (14, -9) to[out=318,in=125] (20,-16);
\fill (-14,-9) circle (0.15cm);
\fill (14,-9) circle (0.15cm);    
\draw (-14,-9) -- (0,-15) -- (14,-9);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related but I think you mistyped the last `out` value. It should be 315 instead of 318 to keep the same tangent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[green] (-14,-9) to [out=45,in=180] (0,-2) to[out=0,in=135] (14, -9) -- (0,-15) -- cycle;
  \draw [ultra thick,red] (-19.5,-16) to[out=55,in=228] (-14,-9) to [out=45,in=180] (0,-2) to[out=0,in=135] (14, -9) to[out=318,in=125] (20,-16);
  \fill (-14,-9) circle (0.15cm);
  \fill (14,-9) circle (0.15cm);    
  \draw (-14,-9) -- (0,-15) -- (14,-9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Filled area]

---

Edit just to show a `\fillbetween` - this is not a good solution here.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.fillbetween}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [ultra thick, red, name path=A] (-19.5,-16) to[out=55, in=228] (-14,-9) to [out=45, in=180] (0,-2) to[out=0, in=135] (14, -9) to[out=318, in=125] (20,-16);
  \fill (-14,-9) circle (0.15cm);
  \fill (14,-9) circle (0.15cm);    
  \draw[name path=B] (-14,-9) -- (0,-15) -- (14,-9);
  \tikzfillbetween[of=A and B, split, every segment no 0/.style={fill=none}, every segment no 1/.style={green}, every segment no 2/.style={fill=none}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This fill is done after the paths has been `\draw`n and thereby overwrites part of the lines. -this can be solved.

Comment: The kink at `(-14,-9)` (and `(14, -9)`) might be on purpose!? `228-45<>180`

Comment: Good spot with the kink. This solutions suits me, but is there a more general way to fill between paths (so one doesn't need a defined closed shape?)

Comment: This is the solution -use a closed path!! When it is not possible, you can use `\clip` and when that is not possible, you can use `pgfplots.fillbetween`. It is easier to help in a new question with a concrete example - do a search on this site for `fillbetween` first - most likely there are already examples/answer for what you need.

Comment: Example of using `\clip` to fill a shape: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570797/8650